# Can NotificationTokens be held outside of the thread that they are made within?

Tags: swift, realm

(I wasn't able to find this information in the documentation, or don't know where to look, so forgive me if this is already been explained somewhere (link would be helpful).

My app creates and uses NSThreads to interact with Realm. All threads have working Run Loops set up on them so the Realms created on them will autorefresh.

One thread, called ReadThread, is used by the app by different modules to set up notification tokens so that they can receive updates and do some processing without blocking the main thread.

Example (Pseudocode:

```
ReadThread {
  func performAsync(_ block: ()->Void) { 
    // execute block on run loop of the thread using self.perform(#selector(), on: self)
  }
}

Singleton {
  let readThread: ReadThread()

  init {
    self.readThread.start()
  }
}

Main Thread:

Class A {
   private var token: NotificationToken?


  init {
    Singleton.readThread.perform {
      let token = realm.observe() { [weak self] (notification: Realm.Notification, realm) in
                    self?.doWork()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                      self?.notifyUI()  
                    }
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {[weak self] in self?.token = token }
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is that the token is created on the ReadThread, but the token is stored in an instance variable on a different thread (main thread). Is the token thread-safe enough that the main thread objects can at lease call invalidate() on the token, or if the main thread object is deallocated, the token will be automatically invalidated?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learned the hard was, but the answer is no, the omens must be invalidated under the same thread that the token was generated under. Otherwise, a runtime exception will be thrown by Realm.verifyThread check.